# cannot retrieve php variable until echoed

Tags: php, variables, echo

I had recently a strange issue in my code. I needed to check for variable value in the if statement, but it always failed, value was (false), after echoing the value everything worked.

example (I can't remember exact code):

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$limit; $i++) {
   if ($object->data[$i]['name']) {
      echo 'name: '.$object->data[$i]['name'];
   }
}
```

Script above always returned false (didn't display user name)

Script below worked however (even when I commented the echo statement)

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$limit; $i++) {
   // echo $object->data[$i]['name'];
   if ($object->data[$i]['name']) {
      echo 'name: '.$object->data[$i]['name'];
   }
}
```

Have this happened to anyone? Is there a reason for this?

Okay... here is the original code:

```
<?php if ( $data->apartments[$i]['price']['price1']->value ) { ?>
<div class="prices">
   <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse">
       <tr>
           <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #E36300">
               <h3>PRICE LIST</h3>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

   <?php

   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price_date1']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price_date2']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price_date3']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price_date4']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price_date5']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price_date6']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price_date7']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price_date8']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price_date9']->value;

   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price1']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price2']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price3']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price4']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price5']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price6']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price7']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price8']->value;
   //$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price9']->value;

   for ( $pc=0; $pc<=10; $pc++ ) {

       if ( $data->apartments[$i]['price']['price_date'.$pc]->value ) {
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td style='border: 1px solid #E36300' align='left' valign='top' width='50%'>".$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price_date'.$pc]->value."</td>";
           echo "<td style='border: 1px solid #E36300' align='right' valign='top' width='50%'>".$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price'.$pc]->value." ".$data->apartments[$i]['price']['price_currency']->value."</td>";
           echo "</tr>";
       } 
   }
   ?>

   </table>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you need to "remember" the exact code..

Comment: If you can't remember exact code, we can't exactly help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the var you were trying to echo/output, and thus checking on, was something that evaluates to **false**. Note that there are a couple of things that could evaluate to false, even tho the var is filled/non-empty. i.e. **0**, **null** etc..

To check wether a var is set, use isset(). And not just if($var)..

But, as said as a comment above, this is just a guess. You'll have to provide us/me with the exact code to be certain.